# Graph plot in python using tkinter

Tags: python, plot, tkinter

I have to make a program in python that plots function based on *txt file. The file contains 20 x values (x range from -10 to 10) in the first column and 20 y values in the next column. I've managed to create a window with file opening button, I've also drawn axis etc. The only problem is that values read from the txt file don't correspond with coordinates in program. This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog


class Program(tk.Frame,tk.Canvas):

def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
    self.parent = parent
    self.kanwa = tk.Canvas(self)
    self.kanwa.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    self.initUI()
    self.rys_osi()
    self.znaczniki()


def initUI(self):

    self.parent.title("Program")
    self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    menubar = tk.Menu(self.parent)
    self.parent.config(menu=menubar)

    fileMenu = tk.Menu(menubar)
    fileMenu.add_command(label="Otwórz", command=self.otworz_plik)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Plik", menu=fileMenu)
    self.kanwa.create_text(5, 5, anchor=tk.NW, font="Helvetica 18 bold", fill="blue", text="Wykres funkcji")  #tytul
    self.kanwa.create_text(780, 270, font="Helvetica 14 bold", fill="black", text="0X")  #tytul OX

def rys_osi(self):   
    self.kanwa.create_line(400, 600, 400, 0, arrow=tk.LAST, arrowshape=(13,17,6), width=3) #os y (x0,y0,x1,y1), grubosc 3px
    self.kanwa.create_line(0, 300, 800, 300, arrow=tk.LAST, arrowshape=(13,17,6), width=3) #os x, domyslny arrowshape (d1,d2,d3=8,10,3)

def znaczniki(self):    
    for i in range(21):
        x = i * 38
        self.kanwa.create_line(x+20,310,x+20,290, width=2)                                       #rysowanie znacznikow na osi x
    for j in range(21):
        y = j * 27
        self.kanwa.create_line(410,y+30,390,y+30, width=2)                                       #rysowanie znacznikow na osi y


def otworz_plik(self):

    typ_pliku = [('Pliki tekstowe', '*.txt'), ('Wszystkie pliki', '*')]                    #domyslny typ pliku - *txt
    dlg = tk.filedialog.Open(self, filetypes = typ_pliku)
    fl = dlg.show()

    if fl != '':
        text = self.czytaj_plik(fl)
        self.konwersja(text)

def czytaj_plik(self, filename):

    f = open(filename, "r")
    text = f.read()
    return text

def konwersja(self, text):                  #OPERACJE NA WCZYTANYCH PUNTACH
    x = [line.split()[0] for line in text.splitlines()] #podział wiersza na wartości x i y 
    y = [line.split()[1] for line in text.splitlines()]
    x1 = [float(arg) for arg in x]                      #konwersja x -> float
    y1 = [float(arg) for arg in y]                  #konwersja y -> float   
    punkty = zip (x1,y1)                                #punkty (x,y) zzipowane funkcja
    arg = max(abs(min(y1)),max(y1))                     #maksymalna wartosc y
    skala = arg/10                                  #podziel max wart y przez 10 - uzyskuje podzialke
    wart_y = []

    for i in range (11):  #petla wpisujaca wartosci skali y do listy wart_y
        wart_y.append(i)  #inicjalizacja listy ???
        wart_y[i]=skala*i
    wart_y.reverse()    #odwrocenie kolejnosci argumentow w liscie
    print(x)
    print(y)
    print (arg,"MAX Y")
    print(wart_y)
    self.etykiety_x(x)
    self.etykiety_y(wart_y)
    self.rysuj(x1,y1)

def etykiety_x(self,x):    
    for i in range(21):
        q = i * 38
        self.kanwa.create_text(q+15, 320, font="Helvetica 10", fill="black", text=x[i])   #etykiety osi x - po prostu nazywa od stringow

def etykiety_y(self,wart_y):    
    for i in range(11):
        q = i * 27
        self.kanwa.create_text(430, q+30, font="Helvetica 10", fill="black", text=wart_y[i])   #etykiety osi y - dodatnie
    j = 9
    while j >= 0:
        u = j * 27
        self.kanwa.create_text(430, 570-u, font="Helvetica 10", fill="black", text=wart_y[j])   #etykiety osi y - ujemne
        j=j-1
        print(j,wart_y[j])

def rysuj(self,x1,y1):
    punkty = []
    punkty = zip(x1,y1)
    self.kanwa.create_line(*punkty, fill='red', width = 3)


def main():

app = tk.Tk()
Program(app)
app.geometry("800x600")   #rozmiar okna
app.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

And the thx file looks like that:

```
-10 150
-9  114
...
10  190
```

I'm very beginner in coding, so i do not know how to covert the function values to coordinates on the screen.

Comment: Doesn't exactly help you now, but `tkinter` is painful when it comes to making mathematical plots. Use `matplotlib` instead: http://matplotlib.org/ , at least for future projects.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have to do this without using any external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

## I do notice that your if statement at the bottom:

`if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()`

## should be indented as shown.